# JMeter - Bandwidth control not working

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, bandwidth-throttling

I'm attempting to run a testplan using different qualities of network.
To accomplish this I set a "HTTP Request Default" so they all use HTTP 3.1 or 4.

Then I passed the properties as follows:

-Jhttpclient.socket.http.cps=21888 -Jhttpclient.socket.https.cps=21888

However it doesn't seem like it's doing much, do I need to enable the setting in the user.properties as well (to maybe 0) which I can then overwrite with the property?

I am doing this with a distributed test plan (multiple load generators in non-gui mode) but since they are all started through the one "master" node I would think they would all take the property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start all the slaves using these -J command-line arguments or modify *user.properties* file **on each slave** in order to make it work.

Properties are not being automatically passed to slaves from the master node. You can also try out -G key, as per [Full list of command-line options](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)

```
-G, --globalproperty <argument>=<value>
        Define Global properties (sent to servers)
        e.g. -Gport=123
        or -Gglobal.properties
```

Also remember that all slaves are quite independent so each of them will have 21888 characters per second throttling so cumulative bandwidth will be sum of all slaves.

See [How to Simulate Different Network Speeds in Your JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-simulate-different-network-speeds-your-jmeter-load-test) article for more information on simulating different networks during JMeter test.

Comment: I got my ideas  from that same article. Just tried with adding the parameter in the jmeter.properties (a bit confused about if it should be in user or jmeter) and seems to do the trick!